# Text in UI disappears when clicked on

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a UI system I built for the game. In editor, it works perfectly. But when the game is compiled to an executable and ran, the initial menu text will be invisible unless I switch to a sub menu and switch back

Conversely, the text in a sub menu will disappear whenever I switch quality level using a button. It comes back if I switch menus. Any ideas as to why this is happening?
[Menu before clicking Quality Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAGRo.jpg)
[Menu after clicking Quality Level](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofEci.jpg)

Comment: try changing wrapping options. set them to overflow

Comment: That doesn't work. Also it's not moving off the button, because it'll spazz back into existence if I click it again, then it'll disappear again

Comment: What method did you use to show the text. Please include any relevant code.

Comment: This is the code that changes the quality settings and the text upon clicking. The words are taken from what I named the Quality Settings inside Unity
https://gyazo.com/b687ab5789440f11bce5da88eac44f52

The entire GUI system works by each button throwing a number into this function when clicking the button, and it using a switch system to see which function it should execute from that input

Comment: Try asking this question in http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/